# How do I assign a value to a combo box in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I ahve a combobox item named `cbxType`.
This combo box is filled with:

```vb
cbxType.DataSource = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Customer.CustomerType))
```

Where `Customer.CustomerType` is an enumeration:

```vb
Public Enum CustomerType
    Retail
    SelfEmployed
    Company
End Enum
```

This works fine for populating the Field, but what how can I assign a given value to the combobox later in code?

I have tried:

```vb
cbxType.ValueMember = 0
```

But I get:

```vb
System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the new display member.
Parameter name: newDisplayMember'
```

Comment: I suggest you read the properties of the combo box, you'll most surely find the one you need :)

Comment: SelectedItem works, what is the difference between SelectedValue then?

Comment: In this case, not much. See the end of my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a ComboBox is bound to a collection of some simple entity like an enum X..

- the thing that is displayed in the combo is the string returned by `X.ToString()`,which in this case returns the enum text name, and
- the thing that is returned as the value, of what is shown is the combo, is X.

Hence to change what the combo shows set the `.SelectedValue` of the combo to an object of type X. X in this case would be one of the enum members:

```
cbxType.SelectedValue = CustomerType.SelfEmployed
```

`ValueMember` (and its partner `DisplayMember`) are used to indicate which property of a complex object you'd like the combo to use for the display and the selectedvalue.

For example if you've bound your combo to a `List(Of Person)` and a Person has amongst other things a FullName and an Email properties you might set `DisplayMember = "FullName"` to make the list show "John Smith, Jane Doe.." etc, and you might set a `ValueMember = "Email"` so when John Smith is selected, calling SelectedValue might return you "John.smith@example.com"

SelectedItem would be the whole Person object. SelectedIndex would be the numerical index of the chosen item, in the list of items the combo is showing, but remember that in some cases the list shown can be sorted into a different order than the underlying collection

Comment: Just in case it helps others, if you are using `0` then it would be `cbxType.SelectedItem = 0`. Thanks for the answer this helps me and puts me on the track of using collections.

Comment: You really should use enum member names, not ints that happen to be associated with enum members. Enums don't have to start at 0, and if you refactor your code so Retail is no longer 0 (perhaps you remove retail but want to keep SelfEmployed as 1 etc) then using the name will be a compiler error and you can fix it. Setting 0 will silently compile but the combo will no longer select an item to start with because 0 is no longer in the enum -> use enum names to leverage the entire reason why we use enums in the first place (to avoid magic numbers in code)

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. The reason for using the numbers is that I am storing the Enum in the database using an integer field.

Comment: No probs. In code you should use enum names, regardless of how the data is stored. (And there are ways that you can store the string name in the db too and have it convert when pulled out - makes the database more readable)